# Spring JPA Bean with name sessionFactory is NullPointerException

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

> Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException.

Full stack trace:

```
11:26:23,712 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-7) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) [spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) [spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:190) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:126) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343) [spring-orm-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:431) [spring-orm-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416) [spring-orm-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 21 more

11:26:23,716 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./projectERP: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./projectERP: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:219)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:190)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:431)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 21 more

11:26:23,733 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "projectERP.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./projectERP" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./projectERP: Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"}}
11:26:23,946 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "projectERP.war" (runtime-name : "projectERP.war")
11:26:23,947 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./projectERP: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./projectERP: Failed to start service
```

Spring-jpa.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource"
    jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/dataSource"
    lookup-on-startup="true" proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.package.*.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect" />
            <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <entry key="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="SCHEMA" />
            <entry key="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider"
                value="com.package.security.MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl" />
            <entry key="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver"
                value="com.package.security.MultiTenantIdentifierResolverImpl" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="autodetectDataSource" value="true" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Persistence.xml:

```
<persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">

</persistence-unit>
```

MultiTenantIdentifierResolvImp.class:

```
package com.package.security;

import org.hibernate.context.spi.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MultiTenantIdentifierResolverImpl implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MultiTenantIdentifierResolverImpl.class);

    @Override
    public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
        String tenantResoloved = resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier();

        LOGGER.debug("Tenant Schema resolved by SchemaResolverAdmin " + tenantResoloved);

        return "public";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

MultiTenantConnectionProvider.class:

```
package com.package.security;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.MultiTenantConnectionProvider;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl implements
        MultiTenantConnectionProvider {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9064120876236832566L;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.class);  

    @Override
    public boolean isUnwrappableAs(Class unwrapType) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> unwrapType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier)
            throws SQLException {
        final Connection connection = getAnyConnection();
        try {
            connection.createStatement().execute(
                    "SET schema " + tenantIdentifier);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new HibernateException(
                    "Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema ["
                            + tenantIdentifier + "]", e);
        }
        return connection;

    }

    @Override
    public void releaseConnection(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connection)
            throws SQLException {
        try {
            connection.createStatement().execute("SET schema " + tenantIdentifier);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new HibernateException(
                    "Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema ["
                            + tenantIdentifier + "]", e);
        }
        connection.close();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add the full staktrace please.

Comment: For starters your `packagesToScan` is wrong it isn't a pattern... It also has nothing to do with JPA but hibernate so having a `persistence.xml` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, I recently add the full stack trace in this post @Jens.  Thank you.

Comment: I need to persist entities in my schemas, so I add the property hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto with value update and I will remove the persistence.xml soon @M. Deinum. Thank You.

Comment: Looks like you have a problem in your datasource configuration. Can you check it?